# Saving multiple HTML row values to MySQL using JSP

Tags: html, jsp

On clicking `<button>` `btnSave` on html page, `saveRecords.jsp` is invoked to save the multiple rows of HTML.
The Code in `saveRecords.jsp` is as follows.

```
try{
        String[] table_id = request.getParameterValues("table_id");   
        String[] hall_name = request.getParameterValues("hall_name");
        String[] hall_capacity = request.getParameterValues("hall_capacity");   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chbs?" + "user=root&password=");    

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `halls`(`Hall_ID`, `Hall_Name`, `Capacity`) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
        pst.setString(1, table_id);
        pst.setString(2, hall_name);
        pst.setString(3, hall_capacity);
        int rset = pst.executeUpdate();       
    }
```

However,   PreparedStatement.setString() doesn't accept Array. Since, the HTML table is in one .jsp and the code to save the values of HTML rows in in `saveRecords.jsp` which is different, the `HTML table` values are not getting posted and the `PreparedStatement.setString()` is throwing error. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update in [batch](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/). assuming the values are validated and the arrays length are equal you can `addBatch` each insert and `executeBatch` at the end;

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chbs?" + "user=root&password=");    
String sql = "INSERT INTO `halls`(`Hall_ID`, `Hall_Name`, `Capacity`) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i=0; i< table_id .length;i++) {
   ps.setString(1, table_id [i]);
   ps.setString(2, hall_name [i]);
   ps.setString(3, hall_capacity [i]);

    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Thanks for Prompt response. But now the problem is that the values of HTML Table `id="table_id">` and rest are not getting posted for trapping at `saveRecords.jsp`. Can't I use <td> with ID to post values? In `js` it is working fine.

Comment: Also, in your this `PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);` `connection` becomes `conn` and in `statement.executeBatch();` the `statement` becomes `ps`. Am I correct sir?

Comment: Sir, About the first comment... please advise

Comment: It's a different question

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
        String[] table_id = request.getParameterValues("table_id");   
        String[] hall_name = request.getParameterValues("hall_name");
        String[] hall_capacity = request.getParameterValues("hall_capacity");   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chbs?" + "user=root&password=");    

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `halls`(`Hall_ID`, `Hall_Name`, `Capacity`) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
for(int i=0;i<table_id.lenght;i++){
        pst.setString(1, table_id[i]);
        pst.setString(2, hall_name[i]);
        pst.setString(3, hall_capacity[i]);
        int rset = pst.executeUpdate();       
    }
}
```

It will also work for you.